# Apple Mach-O linker exits error code 1 (possibly a failed assert)

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, llvm-gcc

Has anyone had any experience with this crash from the XCode 4.2 linker:

```
Command /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

No other information was generated, even with -v verbose turned on, however I noticed this showing up in the Console log:

```
1/20/15 11:47:30 AM [0x0-0x1b01b].com.apple.dt.Xcode[240]   2015-01-20 11:47 Xcode[240] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamFlushSync(): failed assertion '(SInt64)last_id > 0LL'
```

The only changes I've made to the project was to strip symbols from various libraries...

NOTE: I've isolated a particular library where I had changed the Strip Style from "Debugging Symbols" to "Non-Global Symbols".  But this really feels like a genuine bug in Xcode 4.2.  The good news is that I assume this is a bug that is fixed in Xcode 5.x and 6.x.  The bad news is that for this particular build I'm stuck with Xcode 4.2.